# C++ include file, .dll library and MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, header, loadlibrary

I have a .dll file with its .h C++ include file:

```
#ifndef _IWEARDRV_H
#define _IWEARDRV_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
// iWear Tracker Product IDs
#define IWR_PROD_NONE               000 // indicated an unsupported product
#define IWR_PROD_VR920              227 // This is equvalent to the IRW_FEATURE_TRACKER_STYLE_0 bit set in product details.
#define IWR_PROD_WRAP920            329 // IWR_PROD_WRAP920 as a define is deprecated
#define IWR_PROD_WRAP               329 // This is equvalent to the IRW_FEATURE_TRACKER_STYLE_1 bit set in product details.
// iWear Tracker Product sub-IDs
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_VR920       0 // No sub IDs for VR920
// Wrap sub IDS
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_WRAP310     1
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_WRAP920     2
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_WRAP280     3
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_WRAP230     4
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_WRAP1200    5
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_STAR1200    6
#define IWR_PROD_DETAIL_WRAP1200AR      7

typedef struct tag_IWRVERSION {
    unsigned short DLLMajor;
    unsigned short DLLMinor;
    unsigned short DLLSubMinor;
    unsigned short DLLBuildNumber;
    char USBFirmwareMajor;
    char USBFirmwareMinor;
    char TrackerFirmwareMajor;
    char TrackerFirmwareMinor;
    char VideoFirmware;
} IWRVERSION, *PIWRVERSION;
typedef struct tag_IWRMAGSENSOR {
    unsigned char magx_lsb;
    unsigned char magx_msb;
    unsigned char magy_lsb;
    unsigned char magy_msb;
    unsigned char magz_lsb;
    unsigned char magz_msb;
} IWRMAGSENSOR, *IWRPMAGSENSOR;
typedef struct tag_IWRACCELSENSOR {
    unsigned char accx_lsb;
    unsigned char accx_msb;
    unsigned char accy_lsb;
    unsigned char accy_msb;
    unsigned char accz_lsb;
    unsigned char accz_msb;
} IWRACCELSENSOR, *PIWRACCELSENSOR;
// High Bandwidth Gyros 2000 degrees per second
// = 1.465 dps/cnt
typedef struct tag_IWRGYROSENSOR {
    unsigned char gyx_lsb;
    unsigned char gyx_msb;
    unsigned char gyy_lsb;
    unsigned char gyy_msb;
    unsigned char gyz_lsb;
    unsigned char gyz_msb;
} IWRGYROSENSOR, *PIWRGYROSENSOR;
// High Bandwidth Gyros 500 degrees per second
// = 0,366 dps/cnt
typedef struct tag_IWRLBGYROSENSOR {
    unsigned char gyx_lsb;
    unsigned char gyx_msb;
    unsigned char gyy_lsb;
    unsigned char gyy_msb;
    unsigned char gyz_lsb;
    unsigned char gyz_msb;
} IWRLBGYROSENSOR, *PIWRLBGYROSENSOR;
typedef struct tag_IWRSENSDATA {
    IWRMAGSENSOR mag_sensor;
    IWRACCELSENSOR acc_sensor;
    IWRGYROSENSOR gyro_sensor;
    IWRLBGYROSENSOR lbgyro_sensor;
} IWRSENSDATA, *PIWRSENSDATA;

/// Parse the subid out of the product details returned by IWRGetProductDetails()
#define IWR_GET_SUBID( x )          ((x & IWR_FEATURE_SUB_ID_MASK) >> 16)

/// Parse the aspect ratio out of the product details returned by IWRGetProductDetails()
#define IWR_GET_ASPECT_RATIO( x )   (x & IWR_FEATURE_ASPECT_RATIO_MASK)

/// Parse the tracker style out of the product details returned by IWRGetProductDetails()
#define IWR_GET_TRACKER_STYLE( x )  (x & IWR_FEATURE_TRACKER_STYLE_MASK)

// Product feature flags as returned by IWRGetProductDetails.
// This contains some information about the hardware associated with this tracker.
// Supported and best resolutions of the associated iWear come from the DDC info 
// and should be handled as any other DDC info.
// Tracker style is shorthand for for the kind of information the tracker returns.
#define IWR_FEATURE_TRACKER_STYLE_MASK  0x00000003

// Style 0 is the VR920.  This tracker is built in.
// It doesn't return data from IWRGetFilteredSensorData(), 
// IWRGetMagYaw(), or IWRGetSensorData()
// It doesn't return translation data from IWRGet6DTracking()
#define IWR_FEATURE_TRACKER_STYLE_0     0x00000000

// Style 1 is the wrap line.  This tracker pluggs into a port and may not always be present.
#define IWR_FEATURE_TRACKER_STYLE_1     0x00000001

// The upper 16 flag bits are dedicated the the associated iWear hardware.
// SubID as listed above.
#define IWR_FEATURE_SUB_ID_MASK         0x000F0000

#define IWR_FEATURE_ASPECT_RATIO_MASK   0x07000000
#define IWR_FEATURE_ASPECT_RATIO_4x3    0x00000000
#define IWR_FEATURE_ASPECT_RATIO_16x9   0x01000000
#define IWR_FEATURE_ASPECT_RATIO_16x10  0x02000000

#define IWR_FEATURE_SEETHROUGH          0x08000000
#define IWR_FEATURE_WINDOWED_3D         0x10000000 // All iWear supports FullScreen 3D, only some supports windowed 3D.
#define IWR_FEATURE_USB_PSCAN_3D        0x20000000 // Supports Progressive scan USB stereoscopy
#define IWR_FEATURE_SIDE_X_SIDE         0x40000000 // Supports side by side stereoscopy

#ifndef IWEARDRV_EXPLICIT
#ifdef IWEARDRV_EXPORTS
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWROpenTracker( void );
__declspec( dllexport ) void __cdecl    IWRCloseTracker( void );
__declspec( dllexport ) void __cdecl    IWRZeroSet( void );
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRGetTracking(LONG *yaw, LONG *pitch, LONG *roll);
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRGet6DTracking(LONG *yaw, LONG *pitch, LONG *roll, LONG *xtrn, LONG *ytrn, LONG *ztrn);
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRGetFilteredSensorData(LONG *ax, LONG *ay, LONG *az, LONG *lgx, LONG *lgy, LONG *lgz, LONG *gx, LONG *gy, LONG *gz, LONG *mx, LONG *my, LONG *mz);
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRGetSensorData(PIWRSENSDATA sensdataptr);
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRBeginCalibrate(void);
__declspec( dllexport ) void __cdecl    IWREndCalibrate(BOOL save);
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRGetVersion(PIWRVERSION ver);
__declspec( dllexport ) void __cdecl    IWRSetFilterState(BOOL on);
__declspec( dllexport ) BOOL __cdecl    IWRGetFilterState(void);
__declspec( dllexport ) WORD __cdecl    IWRGetProductID(void);
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRGetProductDetails(void);
__declspec( dllexport ) void __cdecl    IWRSetMagAutoCorrect(BOOL on);
__declspec( dllexport ) DWORD __cdecl   IWRGetMagYaw(LONG *myaw);
#else
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWROpenTracker( void );
__declspec( dllimport ) extern void     IWRCloseTracker( void );
__declspec( dllimport ) extern void     IWRZeroSet( void );
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWRGetTracking(LONG *yaw, LONG *pitch, LONG *roll);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWRGet6DTracking(LONG *yaw, LONG *pitch, LONG *roll, LONG *xtrn, LONG *ytrn, LONG *ztrn);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWRGetFilteredSensorData(LONG *ax, LONG *ay, LONG *az, LONG *lgx, LONG *lgy, LONG *lgz, LONG *gx, LONG *gy, LONG *gz, LONG *mx, LONG *my, LONG *mz);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWRGetSensorData(PIWRSENSDATA sensdataptr);
__declspec( dllexport ) extern DWORD    IWRBeginCalibrate(void);
__declspec( dllexport ) extern void     IWREndCalibrate(BOOL save);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWRGetVersion(PIWRVERSION ver);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern void     IWRSetFilterState(BOOL on);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern BOOL     IWRGetFilterState(void);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern WORD     IWRGetProductID(void);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWRGetProductDetails(void);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern void     IWRSetMagAutoCorrect(BOOL on);
__declspec( dllimport ) extern DWORD    IWRGetMagYaw(LONG *myaw);
#endif
#else
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWROPENTRACKER)( void );
typedef void    (__cdecl *PIWRCLOSETRACKER)( void );
typedef void    (__cdecl *PIWRZEROSET)( void );
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRGETTRACKING)(LONG *, LONG *, LONG *);
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRGET6DTRACKING)(LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *);
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRGETFILTEREDSENSORDATA)(LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *, LONG *);
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRGETSENSORDATA)(PIWRSENSDATA);
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRGETVERSION)(PIWRVERSION);
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRBEGINCALIBRATE)( void );
typedef void    (__cdecl *PIWRENDCALIBRATE)( BOOL );
typedef void    (__cdecl *PIWRSETFILTERSTATE)( BOOL );
typedef BOOL    (__cdecl *PIWRGETFILTERSTATE)(void);
typedef WORD    (__cdecl *PIWRGETPRODUCTID)(void);
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRGETPRODUCTDETAILS)(void);
typedef void    (__cdecl *PIWRSETMAGAUTOCORRECT)( BOOL );
typedef DWORD   (__cdecl *PIWRGETMAGYAW)(LONG *);

#ifdef IWEAR_ONETIME_DEFINITIONS
    HMODULE                     IWRTrackerInstance=NULL;
    PIWROPENTRACKER             IWROpenTracker=NULL;
    PIWRCLOSETRACKER            IWRCloseTracker=NULL;
    PIWRZEROSET                 IWRZeroSet=NULL;
    PIWRGETTRACKING             IWRGetTracking=NULL;
    PIWRGET6DTRACKING           IWRGet6DTracking=NULL;
    PIWRGETFILTEREDSENSORDATA   IWRGetFilteredSensorData=NULL;
    PIWRGETSENSORDATA           IWRGetSensorData=NULL;
    PIWRGETVERSION              IWRGetVersion=NULL;
    PIWRBEGINCALIBRATE          IWRBeginCalibrate=NULL;
    PIWRENDCALIBRATE            IWREndCalibrate=NULL;
    PIWRSETFILTERSTATE          IWRSetFilterState=NULL;
    PIWRGETFILTERSTATE          IWRGetFilterState=NULL;
    PIWRGETPRODUCTID            IWRGetProductID=NULL;
    PIWRGETPRODUCTDETAILS       IWRGetProductDetails=NULL;
    PIWRSETMAGAUTOCORRECT       IWRSetMagAutoCorrect=NULL;
    PIWRGETMAGYAW               IWRGetMagYaw=NULL;
#else
    extern HMODULE              IWRTrackerInstance;
    extern PIWROPENTRACKER      IWROpenTracker;
    extern PIWRCLOSETRACKER     IWRCloseTracker;
    extern PIWRZEROSET          IWRZeroSet;
    extern PIWRGETTRACKING      IWRGetTracking;
    extern PIWRGET6DTRACKING    IWRGet6DTracking;
    extern PIWRGETFILTEREDSENSORDATA IWRGetFilteredSensorData;
    extern PIWRGETSENSORDATA    IWRGetSensorData;
    extern PIWRGETVERSION       IWRGetVersion;
    extern PIWRBEGINCALIBRATE   IWRBeginCalibrate;
    extern PIWRENDCALIBRATE     IWREndCalibrate;
    extern PIWRSETFILTERSTATE   IWRSetFilterState;
    extern PIWRGETFILTERSTATE   IWRGetFilterState;
    extern PIWRGETPRODUCTID     IWRGetProductID;
    extern PIWRGETPRODUCTDETAILS IWRGetProductDetails;
    extern PIWRSETMAGAUTOCORRECT IWRSetMagAutoCorrect;
    extern PIWRGETMAGYAW        IWRGetMagYaw;
#endif
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // _IWEARDRV_H
```

I am not a C++ developer but I need to load this library into matlab (matlab2013b x64 with Win7 x64, .dll and .h are x64 versions) because I need to use functions written in the h-file. I tried with 'loadlibrary' matlab function but it returns many errors:

```
Error using loadlibrary (line 418)
Building iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64 failed.  Compiler output is:
cl -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\include"   /W3
/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0
/nologo  -I"C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB"
-I"C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB" "iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c" -LD
-Fe"iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.dll"
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(181) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWROpenTracker'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(181) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(181) : error C2059: syntax error
: 'type'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(184) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetTracking'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(184) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(184) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ')' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(184) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing '{' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(184) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(184) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(184) : error C2059: syntax error
: ')'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGet6DTracking'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ')' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing '{' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(185) : error C2059: syntax error
: ')'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetFilteredSensorData'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ')' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing '{' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ';' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(186) : error C2059: syntax error
: ')'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(187) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetSensorData'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(187) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(187) : error C2059: syntax error
: 'type'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(188) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRBeginCalibrate'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(188) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(188) : error C2059: syntax error
: 'type'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(189) : error C2146: syntax error
: missing ')' before identifier 'save'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(189) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'save'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(189) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(189) : error C2059: syntax error
: ')'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(190) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetVersion'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(190) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(190) : error C2059: syntax error
: 'type'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(191) : error C2146: syntax error
: missing ')' before identifier 'on'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(191) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'on'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(191) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(191) : error C2059: syntax error
: ')'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(192) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetFilterState'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(192) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(192) : error C2059: syntax error
: 'type'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(193) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetProductID'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(193) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(193) : error C2059: syntax error
: 'type'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(194) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetProductDetails'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(194) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(194) : error C2059: syntax error
: 'type'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(195) : error C2146: syntax error
: missing ')' before identifier 'on'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(195) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'on'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(195) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(195) : error C2059: syntax error
: ')'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(196) : error C2061: syntax error
: identifier 'IWRGetMagYaw'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(196) : error C2059: syntax error
: ';'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(196) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing ')' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(196) : error C2143: syntax error
: missing '{' before '*'
C:\Users\User\Documents\MATLAB\iweardrv.h(196) : error C2059: syntax error
: ')'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(129) : error C2065: 'BOOL' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(129) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'p0'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(129) : error C2065: 'p0' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(130) : error C2065: 'p0' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(130) : error C2065: 'BOOL' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(130) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')'
before 'const'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(130) : error C2100: illegal indirection
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(130) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(131) : error C2065: 'p0' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(131) : error C2065: 'p0' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(131) : error C2065: 'p0' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(132) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')'
before identifier 'BOOL'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(132) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')'
before identifier 'BOOL'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(132) : error C2065: 'BOOL' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(132) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(132) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'fcn'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(132) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(132) : error C2065: 'p0' : undeclared identifier
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(136) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier
'BOOLvoidThunk'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(136) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(136) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(142) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier
'WORDvoidThunk'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(142) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
iweardrv_thunk_pcwin64.c(142) : error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

I think it returns error because loadlibrary command import C libraries and not C++. Some suggestion ?

Comment: some of those definitions seem to require the "windows.h" header file (HMODULE, DWORD, BOOL, ..)? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98991. IMO it might be easier to write a MEX-function to interface with the library instead of using `loadlibrary`..

Comment: Thank you very much for reply! I would try load it in MATLAB first, after this I will try to do mex file. Where have I to put header and .dll file ? I copied iweardrv.h and its dll in MATLAB directory inside Documents folder, is it right?

Comment: I added to matlab search path: 1)windows sdk include/lib folders 2) include/lib folders of .dll and iweardrv.h files. Error is the same.

Comment: I used: [n,w] = loadlibrary('iweardrv.dll','iweardrv.h','addheader','Windows.h'); same error

Comment: You need to add more header files. For example type PIWROPENTRACKER is not found. Look for the .h file that defines this type.